# microsoft c\c++ optimizing compiler has stopped working

Tags: templates, c++11, crash, visual-studio-2015

[image]

I'm debugging cpp  code with visual studio 2015. Out of no where, after using some templates (not something new in this code even) I get this message.
Can anyone help please?

Comment: What does `view problem details` show in the attachment?

Comment: Sorry it has vanished after I chose to close the program.. Thank you for your reply